# How to handle GCM upstream messaging error cases?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using "Upstream messaging" feature of GCM to send registration id to backend.
You need to sign the form to use this functionality, which i did but doesn't receive a confirmation yet.

Basicly what i'm doing is calling `register` and then sending obtained id using `send(SENDER_ID@gcm.googleapis.com, msgId, 0, data)`. So TTL is 0. But im still receiving an error in my broadcast receiver (gcm messageType is "send_error" with "error"="SERVICE_NOT_AVAILBLE", probably because "upstream" is not enabled yet for this project).

The point is how can i ensure that the message was successfully delivered? I can receive a message on an error, but there is no message in case of success.

Should i send an extra message to device from my server that everything was OK and wait on a client side for that message?
I think i can rephrase last questing: "Can i make a synchronous `send()`?". I don't need a TTL (thats why i'm sending 0 TTL), just want to send registration id to my server over the cloud (GCM).

Answer (score 0):

this is best example to GCM Notification from server to android.
(android-to-could)

[reference link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

this is best example for cloud-to-message in android

[reference link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

I hope its useful to you.

Comment: I'm talking about device-to-cloud (upstream), not cloud-to-device (downstream). The link you provide has an exmaple of cloud-to-device messaging.

Comment: Its still cloud-to-device. I'm sending a message in the opposite direction.